# Changing from row to column with Shell script command

Tags: text-processing, table

I'm using UNIX language to extract my files. I used this command to extract it:

```
value_1=$(cat tmp.csv | head -1001 | cut -f 3-6 -d','> tmp1.csv)
value_2=$(cat tmp.csv | head -2002 | tail -1001 | cut -f 4-6 -d','> tmp2.csv)
paste -d ',' tmp1.csv tmp2.csv > final.csv
```

My "tmp.csv" file is :

```
0   0   0   17.92204    -3.017933   35.14229
1   0   1   18.27151    -3.179997   35.20044
2   0   2   18.22776    -3.566021   34.87167
                      .
                      .
0   1   0   20.89817    -2.37854    66.51003
1   1   1   21.48396    -2.461451   66.48988
2   1   2   21.78348    -2.575202   66.51389
```

But the result is like this :

```
0   17.92204    -3.017933   35.14229
    20.89817    -2.37854    66.51003
1   18.27151    -3.179997   35.20044
    21.48396    -2.461451   66.48988
2   18.22776    -3.566021   34.87167
    21.78348    -2.575202   66.51389
```

I want to make the result like this :

```
0   17.92204    -3.017933   35.14229    20.89817    -2.37854    66.51003
1   18.27151    -3.179997   35.20044    21.48396    -2.461451   66.48988
2   18.22776    -3.566021   34.87167    21.78348    -2.575202   66.51389
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to achieve that without manually handling?

Comment: post a testable fragment of your `tmp.csv`

Comment: Thank your for the comment Mr. Roman, I have just added the "tmp.csv" file above

Answer (score 0):

If we can base on the fact that first line has 4 items and second 3, we could do this for example using awk:

```
$ cat input-file | awk '{if(NF==4){aa=$0} else {print aa" "$0;}}' > output-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous output which you mentioned in question I believe that is the output of final.csv

```
0   17.92204    -3.017933   35.14229
    20.89817    -2.37854    66.51003
1   18.27151    -3.179997   35.20044
    21.48396    -2.461451   66.48988
2   18.22776    -3.566021   34.87167
    21.78348    -2.575202   66.51389
```

Use this command

```
cat final.csv | sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

Output

```
0   17.92204    -3.017933   35.14229     20.89817    -2.37854    66.51003
1   18.27151    -3.179997   35.20044     21.48396    -2.461451   66.48988
2   18.22776    -3.566021   34.87167     21.78348    -2.575202   66.51389
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me Mr. Praveen but it is still doesn't work

Comment: @ahmadadilah Please post the output which you are getting

Comment: I still get the same output like 'final.csv' file

Comment: Refer the below pasted link i tested with example

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TMr4Cqj7

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr. Praveen it is work now but the output showing only even rows, the odd rows is missing